# Validation for textbox that shoud not allow greater than a number

Tags: javascript

I have a text box like,

```
 <input type="text" id="hourField" value=""/>
```

How can we restrict that text box should not allow greater than 12. (i.e 12hr format, this should allow 1 to 12 numbers only. it should not allow grater than 12.

Comment: Get the value, call `parseInt()` to convert it to a number, and check if it's between 1 and 12. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can jquery for this. Like this

```
var hour_val = $('#hourField').val();
if(hour_val > 12)
{
    alert('Number should be less than 12');
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged....

Comment: What Dipesh ....i don't understand ur point ..can u explain in detail.

Comment: OP did not added jQuery as tag in question..

Answer (score 1):

```
var ele = document.getElementById('hourField');

if(parseInt(ele.value , 10) > 12)
{
    alert('value is bigger than 12');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(doc) {
    var oIn = doc.getElementById('hourField');
    var nIn = oIn.value;
    oIn.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        if(this.value > 12) {
            alert('Cannot exceed 12');
            this.focus();
        }
    });
})(document);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwk92/)

Answer (score 0):

Makue sure that you are restricting input to numbers and then validate input value to check number greater than 12 or not.

Try:

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
           if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
             return false;
           }
            var x=document.getElementById("hourField").value;
           console.log(x);
  if (parseInt(x,10)>12){
    alert("Value is greater than 12");
    return false;
  }
          return true;
       }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6dDwm/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

1st be sure its a num and then check for value.Make a function for repeat use.

```
function isNum(element, msg) {
    var reg= /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (elem.value.match(reg)) {
        if (element.value < 12) {
            return true;
        }
    } else {

        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```